# Inheritance in OOP-inheriting everything and overriding nothing

Tags: oop, inheritance, language-agnostic, factory-pattern

I'm working in an OOP language (C++). I have a base class called Terrain. In my world, every subclass of Terrain--Forest, Grass, Desert, etc.--**inherits every method of Terrain and overrides nothing**. Everything a subclass does, the base class does. It seems like a waste of effort to do this, after realizing that everything I can conceive a subclass doing can just be done by the base class.

Does this mean I should abandon inheritance and work with a different method? My initial idea was to use a factory pattern to generate Terrain objects and construct them with the assignments the subclasses would have in their constructors. For example, the factory would take "desert" as an input param. and generate a Terrain object with a sandy texture, add some cacti, set a dryness property, etc. However, this does not strike me as a perfect solution. For example, with this method you can't distinguish between Desert or Grass, or any such objects, on the basis of their type.

Comment: The factory pattern and inheritance do not contradict with each other. You do not benefit from using your inheritance model yet, but you might in the future, when your terrain types start to differ from each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are totally on the mark. If the data structure is the same, and the methods are all the same, and its just different property values that are required, then the Factory pattern is the way to go.  Inheritance will just require tons of extra code and maintenance.